# Django iterate on template with 2 dicts from views.py

Tags: python, django, html, loops, dictionary

I have the following code :

views.py file :

```
twittdict = {'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6}
twitlistdict = {'A' : 'a', 'B': 'b', 'C': 'c'}
return render(request, 'homepageapp/home.html', {'twittdict' : twittdict, 
'twitlistdict' : twitlistdict})
```

homepage.html file :

```
{% for user in twitlistdict %}
                          <a 
href="https:*/{{ twittdict.user.3 }}"> 
<div class="card border-white mb-3">
                   <p class="card-title"><div class="media">
            <img class="mr-3 align-self-center" 
src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/90x94">
            <div class="media-body">
                <h5>{{ twittdict.user.0 }}</h5>
                <h6>@{{ twittdict.user.1 }}</h6>
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div></p>
                    <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" 
src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/301x200" alt="">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text">{{ twittdict.user.4 }}</p>
                        <p class="card-text">
                           <hr>
                            <i class="fas fa-retweet">{{ twittdict.user.6 }} 
</i> <i class="far fa-heart">{{ twittdict.user.5 }}</i> <span class="pl-5"> 
{{ twittdict.user.2 }}</span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                      </div>{% endfor %}
```

When i preview the page with the browser, instead of loop items ( eg: twittdict.user.2 corresponding value ), nothing is showed. Blank.
How can i made this work and display correct values in the page ?
Really struggling with this. Any help is greatly appreciated
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The keys in your `twitlistdict` (e.g. 'A', 'B') do not correspond to any keys in `twittdict` (e.g. '0', '1').

Also you can not get a variable index in the template by using `twittdict.user`, it will try to get `twittdict['user']`. Accessing by numeric keys will only work with lists, not with dictionaries.

Try to form one dictionary in python instead of two, that will make working with it easier in the template. A useful thing might be to use `dict.items()` to get both the key and the value of a dict item:

```
{% for key, value in my_dict.items() %} 
  {{ key }}: {{ value }} 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: When i put that code, i get : TemplateSyntaxError at /
Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'twitlistdict.items()'